# How to Play a music in the background vb6?

Tags: audio, vb6

hi i make a small game with vb6 and i need play 2 sound in some time 
i use this code

```css
 Private Declare Function PlaySoundMem Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As Long, ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
    Const SND_ASYNC = &H1, SND_MEMORY = &H4, SND_NODEFAULT = &H2, SND_NOSTOP = &H1, SND_NOWAIT = &H2000
Dim Sound() As Byte
Dim x As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error Resume Next
Sound = LoadResData("music", "CUSTOM")
Call PlaySoundMem(VarPtr(Sound(0)), 0, SND_NOWAIT Or SND_NODEFAULT Or SND_MEMORY Or SND_ASYNC Or SND_NOSTOP)
DoEvents

End Sub

Private Sub snd()
If nrd.Text = 1 Then
x = 1
snd_hero
ElseIf nrd.Text = 2 Then
x = 2
snd_hero
ElseIf nrd.Text = 3 Then
x = 3
snd_hero
ElseIf nrd.Text = 4 Then
x = 4
snd_hero
ElseIf nrd.Text = 5 Then
x = 5
snd_hero
ElseIf nrd.Text = 6 Then
x = 6
snd_hero
End If
End Sub

Private Sub snd_hero()
On Error Resume Next
Sound = LoadResData(x, "CUSTOM")
Call PlaySoundMem(VarPtr(Sound(0)), 0, SND_NOWAIT Or SND_NODEFAULT Or SND_MEMORY Or SND_ASYNC Or SND_NOSTOP)
DoEvents
ReDim Sound(0)
```

its play music whin game start but the music stop whin play another sound 
i need play to sound at some time what i do thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a windows media player control and set it to loop. Since it behaves like an external media player (to some extent) it mixes the audio into directshow, so it will not prevent other sounds from playing, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?574868-RESOLVED-playing-two-audio-clips-at-the-same-time) out.  It's for VB.Net, but it looks like the only thing you need to change is the button click event handler.  mciSendString is part of the WinAPI for MCI devices (winmm.dll), which is just as easy to use in VB6.

Comment: that good example but that in vb.net  , i dont know how can use him  if u can convert that code to vb 6 plz thx

Comment: I'll be happy to do that for you.  My rates are $150 an hour, and it should take about an hour.  Any other work you need done, perhaps you can let me know ahead of time and I'll work up a quote for the whole lot.  Once we work out how I'm going to get paid, and sign contracts and all, I'll get started.  If you want to do it yourself, then read my explanation more carefully.  If you're confused, ask, and I'll answer.  Answers are free, code isn't.